# Writing F# code to parse "2 + 2" into code

Tags: f#

Extremely just-started-yesterday new to F#.

What I want: To write code that parses the string "2 + 2" into (using as an example code from the tutorial project) Expr.Add(Expr.Num 2, Expr.Num 2) for evaluation. Some help to at least point me in the right direction or tell me it's too complex for my first F# project. (This is how I learn things: By bashing my head against stuff that's hard)

What I have: My best guess at code to extract the numbers. Probably horribly off base. Also, a lack of clue.

```
let script = "2 + 2";

let rec scriptParse xs =
    match xs with
    | [] -> (double)0
    | y::ys -> (double)y

let split = (script.Split([|' '|]))
let f x = (split[x]) // "This code is not a function and cannot be applied."
let list = [ for x in 0..script.Length -> f x ]

let result = scriptParse
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is `Expr.Num`? And do you know how would you solve this using a language you already know?

Comment: I'd strongly consider using the F# Power Pack and using [FsLex / FsYacc](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrsmith/archive/2008/01/18/fslex-sample.aspx) to do this. Writing this from scratch is hard; and easy to get wrong.

Comment: @vcjones, it seems to me that this is a learning exercise, not a real project. So, using a library may not be the best solution.

Comment: @svick - I was suggesting proper tools, not a magic library that does this. A lexical analyser makes this a lot easier; but it isn't a magic wave of the hand. If this is an F# learning exercise, knowing that F# has a really powerful grammar support is a good idea.

Comment: In order: It's a typeexpressionfunctionthingy in the Tutorial project that shows up in the list of starter projects in the "New Projects" list in Visual Studio. :) Thanks for the help. I'll look at those. Yep, this is a learning exercise.

Comment: I would look at this excellent blog post by Jon Harrop: http://fsharpnews.blogspot.com/2010/12/parsing-mathematical-expressions-using.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate issue that you're running into is that `split` is an array of strings.  To access an element of this array, the syntax is `split.[x]`, not `split[x]` (which would apply `split` to the singleton list `[x]`, assuming it were a function).

Here are a few other issues:

1. Your definition of `list` is probably wrong: `x` ranges up to the length of `script`, not the length of the array `split`.  If you want to convert an array or other sequence to a list you can just use `List.ofSeq` or `Seq.toList` instead of an explicit list comprehension `[...]`.
2. Your "casts" to double are a bit odd - that's not the right syntax for performing conversions in F#, although it will work in this case.  `double` is a function, so the parentheses are unnecessary and what you are doing is really calling `double 0` and `double y`.  You should just use `0.0` for the first case, and in the second case, it's unclear what you are converting from.

In general, it would probably be better to do a bit more design up front to decide what your overall strategy will be, since it's not clear to me that you'll be able to piece together a working parser based on your current approach.  There are several well known techniques for writing a parser - are you trying to use a particular approach?

Comment: My knowledge of scripting is limited to a few articles and no books. I have, however, written a primitive and expandable scripting language for C# (albeit only for my own use), so I'm not coming in totally unprepared. Nor is this something I'm planning on completing "immediately"; it's more of an end-goal where I could say "Ok, I've learned this, that and the other" about F#. In the meantime, I wrote a "Guess My Number" game. I did, however, use three mutables. :)